# Outbound call could not connect ( WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state)

Tags: php, twilio

I have multiple instances of our software(PHP application) with same code and deployed on same server.

Twilio is working fine for all other instances but in one(As I mentioned code is 100% same for all) the outbound call could not connect with following unexpected error/exception in the console. 

`- Uncaught Twilio.Exception: 31100: [object Object] 
- WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.`

Tried much but nothing could be figured out.. Want a clue what could be the issue.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Twilio recently moved to version 1.2 from 1.1. Upgrading to the newest version fixed this problem for me.

Comment: I am having the same problem, I did updated to version 1.2 but still getting this error. Any suggestion?